# What do I need to include SQL Server Express in my Wizard installation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, advanced-installer

I've just finished a project with a SQL Serer database, so in my launch project I use this connection string

```
Data Source=(local);Integrated Security=True
```

And I check every time if database exists locally; if not, I execute a script to create the database and tables ... it works 100% without any problems.

But now I want to publish my project in Advanced Installer.. but when I try to install it on another PC, there was a error that said that I can't query database cause server is missing ...

I need the minimum prerequisite to add it in wizard installation, I've tried SQL Server 2005 Express, but it is still not working, the same error ...

Help me please ...

NB : I'm working with SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an *unnamed* default instance on your development PC so that you can connect to it using `data source=(local)`.

When SQL Server **Express** is installed, by default, it uses a **named** instance of `SQLEXPRESS`, so your connection string should have

```
data source=(local)\SQLEXRPESS;....
```

in it, to connect to the `SQLEXPRESS` instance.

Or you need to change your SQL Server Express installation to install as the *default, unnamed instance*, too.

Comment: @AyoubEzzini: if you want to use a SQL Server database on your client PC, you must *either* installed at least SQL Server **Express** on that local PC, or you must be able to connect to an existing server-based SQL Server somewhere in the network that this PC is connected to.

Comment: yes , please can i use (LocalDB) in my connection string ?

Comment: SQL Server "LocalDB" isn't really intended for production use - it's a **developer** tool - so I'd recommend against it - use SQL Server **Express** instead

Comment: ok , but this SQL Server Express instead , it work if i have SQL Server Management Studio 2014 ?

Comment: @AyoubEzzini: sure